# #1146 -Table XXXX doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I use phpmyadmin v4.1.14 Apache version 2.4.9.
After my `wamp` corrupt I copy the whole folder of wamp and install the new one with the same version.

I replace all the folder expect `wampmanager.ini` which was corrupted, but after going to phpmyadmin, all databases don't show any data with error after click any table:

> #1146 -Table XXXX doesn't exist

I try to read some answers here but not working.

Comment: you miss something while copy mysql files, I guess, you are copy your database and leave `mysql`/`information_schema` system databases

Comment: I copy all wamp folders includes sub-folders, lib_logfile0, lib_logfile1 and libdata1

Comment: How did you know `wampmanager,ini` was corrupt. Are you sure it was not your database that was corrupt?

Answer (score 1):

`wampmanager.ini` is re-created every time you start WAMPServer, and when you do a `refresh` from the menu.

If `wampmanager.ini` was really corrupted, then it is **most likely** that `wampmanager.tpl` was actually corrupted, as that file is used by `wampmanager.exe` to rebuild `wampmanager.ini`

However, it is rare for either file to get corrupted unless someone has been playing with the `wampmanager.tpl` file. Always take a copy of `wampmanager.tpl` if you are trying to change it, so you can get back to a working system by restoring your copy.

**Restoring your backup**

The simple way.

If all you think you need from the new install is the `\wampmanager.tpl` and `wampmanager.ini` then this is a simpler solution

On your new install of WAMPServer:

Using the wampmanager menus, do

```
(right click)wampmanager-> Apache-> Service->Remove service
(right click)wampmanager-> MYSQL-> Service-> Remove service
(left click) wampmanager-> exit
```

WAMPServer is basically uninstalled, but no files have been deleted

```
rename C:\wamp\ to C:\wamp_new
```

Now restore your backed up version of WAMPServer

```
copy c:\backup_wamp to C:\wamp
```

Now pick up the 2 files you think are corrupted from the new install and place them in the restored original WAMPServer

```
copy c:\wamp_new\wampmanager.tpl to c:\wamp\wampmanager.tpl
copy c:\wamp_new\wampmanager.ini to c:\wamp\wampmanager.ini
```

Start WAMPServer

Now re-register the Apache and MYSQL services

```
(right click)wampmanager-> Apache-> Service-> Install service
(right click)wampmanager-> MYSQL-> Service-> Install service
```

To make sure the SYMLINKS are correctly rebuilt do

```
(right click)wampmanager-> Apache-> Version-> 2.4.9 (click on the 2.4.9) 

or whatever version you are using
```

Your old WAMPServer should now be reinstalled, but with the new versions of the `wampmanager.ini` and `wampmanager.tpl`

If this does not work, you have not changed your original backup in any way, but you should be back where you were before installing the new WAMPServer, but having replaced the 2 files you think were corrupted.

If this does not come up with your old database intact, then you did not make a complete backup, and I am afraid your database may well be lost for ever.

If all works you can delete the `C:\wamp_new` folder to avoid confusion later

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly but the issue is error " #1146 -Table XXXX doesn't exist" when i try to access the previous database that why I request help to restore my databases from innoDB here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652319/how-to-restore-innodb-in-wamp-server

Comment: Did you make a backup of EVERYTING in `C:\wamp` or did you only copy `/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data/mydatabases`

Comment: I backup everything in c:\wap

Comment: See my suggested restore method and good luck. It does depend upon the fact that you backed up your original installation of WAMPServer correctly

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly  i try the process above but still bring error 1146 , i think the important now it's to help how to restore database from innoDB so i can install fresh one.