# How to restore InnoDB in wamp server?

Tags: mysql, wampserver

My Wampserve use phpmyadmin v4.1.14 and Apache version 2.4.9.
I have databeses folder with **.idb** and **.frm** details also their **ib_logfile0**, **ib_logfile1** and **ibdata1** files.
Please any one can help.

Comment: To be able to restore a database you must have taken a ___backup___ Do you have a backup? Or do you in fact mean ___how do I take a backup___ so I can later ___restore___ my database

Comment: NOTE: phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP that allows us to maintain and manager a **MYSQL** database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#1146 -Table XXXX doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650502/1146-table-xxxx-doesnt-exist) 
 
Asking the same question twice does not improve your chances of an answer!

Comment: I copy whole wamp file also contain databases folder in c/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data/mydatabases .
Sorry I post the second question which is more important to get my databases instead of solve error